# Python 3.x type hints in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using type hints in my Python 3 code. It seems VS Code cannot parse type hints correctly, because syntax highlighting gets messed up (docstrings not highlighted correctly, comments not recognized anymore).

I have all necessary extensions installed (`Python` and `MagicPython` plus `Python for VSCode`). Is there anything else I miss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901572/intellisense-not-recognising-type-hinting-for-python-3

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Brett's solution mentioned in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155987/python-3-x-type-hints-in-visual-studio-code/54528525#comment91294938_52155987) worked for me:

> You might have too many extensions installed. ;) Having `Python` and `Python for VSCode` could be interfering with each other.

When I removed `Python for VSCode`, syntax highlighting began to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I was even considering to change the IDE due to this. Now I know, it was due to the overlapping plugins!!

Comment: Thank you, brother! I was tired of trying, but your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too... I changed my linter to **mypy** and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: I changed my linter to mypy and that alone was not enough, I had to uninstall some old python extensions